# ruby Rake Time BUG in Ruby,what To do now on windows 7:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, i386

ERROR:

```
C:\ruby_shuby\exchange>rake db:create:all
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_ad
apter.rb:620: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i386-mingw32]

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

SYSTEM gem list:

```
C:\ruby_shuby\exchange>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.11, 2.3.2)
actionpack (2.3.11, 2.3.2)
activerecord (2.3.11, 2.3.2)
activeresource (2.3.11, 2.3.2)
activesupport (2.3.11, 2.3.2)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
rack (1.1.2, 1.1.1)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.9.2)
```

HELP! what to do to get done with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "time" bug, it's a problem with your environment not having MySQL installed, I assume.

Have you installed MySQL on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution to above Bug report,which I assume,as the minor problem with database name in mysql and my rails config file..

I found following be the causes of above problem are:

```
>Mysql or database server is Off,or disconnected.
```

**OR** 
`>file in Config/database.yml contains different name of DB` environment like mysql and different Database name which you had setup for your application in rails. (mine was this: MisMatch of Mysql DBname name and DB name in Config/database.yml).

**OR**

```
> mysql or database gem not installed in ruby.
```

**OR**

`>Libmysql.dll file was need to be copy` from Mysql installed directory to ruby's bin directory.,which may some time causes errors like:
[image]